# Google Analytics Goal Funnel

Tags: regex, google-analytics, segment

I have the following scenario which I can not figure out how to set it up correctly. First three steps are ok, but the last part doesn't work ok. The path is:

1.) /something/somethingElse/step1
2.) /something/somethingElse/step2
3.) /something/somethingElse/step3
4.) /email-sent
5.) upon clicking a link in an email, they get redirected to a page which has an utm which contains "RegistrationConfirm". Then from this link, they get redirected to "account" (step 6).
6.) /acccount

I simply can not figure out between step 4 and step 6. Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The funnel is unclear. First 3 steps are page, then it appears to land on a page with an path like /email so an email arrives with a link with utm parameters like this:

> example.com/account?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&**utm_campaign=RegistrationConfirm**

so step 4 in `/email` and the next step is `/account`.